# Getting a value of one variable using a variable + string to call it

Tags: javascript

I have a script to reset game pieces, but I cannot get the variable to call the other variable to get the end value.

Here are the variables that contain original position, I need the value of these in my function:

```
red_1_x = $('#red_1').css('left');
red_1_y = $('#red_1').css('top');
```

Here is my function that calls the animation function:

```
$('.piece').mouseover(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    resetGroundShoe(id);
});
```

$(this).attr('id') is for example: **red_1**

And here is the animation function:

```
function resetPiece(id){
    if(!id){
        alert('no id');
    }
    else{
        x = id+'_x';
        y = id+'_y';
        gotoX = x;
        gotoY = y;
        $('#'+id).animate({left: x}, 250, function(){
            $('#'+id).animate({left: y}, 250);
        });
    }
}
```

For some reason **gotoX** and **gotoY** are not the numeric value of **red_1_x** and **red_1_y**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those are global variables you can use `window[x]` and `window[y]` to access the globals with the names stored in `x`/`y`.

However, using globals is pretty bad style and it really sounds like you should pass those values as arguments!

Comment: Or `obj[x]` in the general case, `window[x]` being a special case.